# Correct way to use coffee script in rails5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, coffeescript, ruby-on-rails-5

I am developing my first rails application and trying to show/hide a particular web element in my view by clicking an another link in my page. Below is my view,

```
%p
 = link_to 'Show additional details', "#", id: "secondary-link"

%table{:id => "secondary"}
 %tr
  %th Key
  %th Value
```

where "secondary-link" is the link which shows / hides my table. When the page is loaded first, the table is made to hide by the following line in my application.css.scss

```
#secondary{
 display: none;
}
```

Also, i have added this following script in my assets/javascripts/application.coffee

```
@myFunction = (variable) ->
  $(document).on "page:change", ->
    $('#secondary-link').click ->
      $('#secondary').toggle()
```

But, the table is not shown when i click the link in my page. However, in my console if i enter "myFunction" i am getting the function

```
ƒ (variable) {
 return $(document).on("page:change", function() {
   return $('#secondary-link').click(function() {
     return $('#secondary').toggle();
   });
 });
}
```

and i am getting an error when i enter myFunction()

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'on' of undefined
at myFunction (application.self-4e74630fd8894bca1e22a8d66c1d7ebfaa39edf4f40e058aae03fc788a9f6d94.js?body=1:3)
at <anonymous>:1:1
```

Your help is appreciated.

Comment: How did you call `myFunction`? Where did you put it?

Comment: in my browser console, i entered "myFunction" and can see its getting loaded. Also, if i click the link "Show additional details" which is supposed to toggle the visibility of another element, the page gets loaded with "#" endpoint.

Comment: You have to call `myFunction()` (with parentheses)

Comment: oops. when i call that myFunction(), i am getting an error "application.self-47d2b709084c7a2d291f788c1a659efac20243f96e18a63b3b4b42285b64978c.js?body=1:3 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'on' of undefined
    at myFunction (application.self-47d2b709084c7a2d291f788c1a659efac20243f96e18a63b3b4b42285b64978c.js?body=1:3)
    at <anonymous>:1:1"

Comment: Cannot read property 'on' of undefined -  Are you using jQuery? its likely you forgot to include a dependency

Comment: I have resolved it by straightly using the jquery.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why this issue but i fixed it by using jquery directly in my application.js file and deleted the coffee file. My js file has the below coding to handle the event.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#secondary-link').click(function(event){
     return $('#secondary').toggle();
  });
});
```

I have stopped and restarted the server and this worked.